# Summoning based on direction player is facing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a jetpack with the new elytra by summoning in exploding creepers behind you to boost you, but I can only do it in one direction. I'm using this command:

```
/execute @e[type=Player,name=CheeseTruffles] ~-4 ~ ~ summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0}
```

But it only hits you in one spot. Is there anyway to make the summoning location depend on the place you're looking?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the `ry` and `rym` selector tags. `ry` is the maximum horizontal rotation, `rym` is the minimum. From Gamepedia:

> Horizontal rotation values vary from -180.0 (facing due north), to -90.0 (facing due east), to 0.0 (facing due south), to 90.0 (facing due west), to 179.9 (just west of due north) before wrapping back to -180.0 (thus horizontal rotation values increase with rotation to the right, or clockwise viewed from above).

Just include the selector tags in your selector. [More info](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_horizontal_rotation)

Answer (score 0):

You could use /testfor commands with comparators coming out of them that test for players facing in every general direction the player could be looking in. These could be attached to the command blocks you wanted to use.